# the closure of union of $C^*$-algebras

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $(A_n)$ is a sequence of $C^*$-algebras,let $B$ be the closure of $\cup A_n$,is $B$ also a $C^*$-algebra?I know the fact that if $A_n$ is increasing,the conclusion is true.(I can show that it is a Banach $*$ algebra,how to show that it satisfies the $C^*$ equation?)

Comment: I think that the increasing property is necessary. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An arbitrary union of subspaces is not in general a subspace. For instance, in $\mathbb C\oplus\mathbb C$  take $A_1=\mathbb C\,(1,0)$, $A_2=A_3=\cdots=\mathbb C\,(0,1)$. Then $\bigcup_nA_n$ does not contain $(1,1)=(1,0)+(0,1)$.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What isomorphism are you talking about?

Comment: If the sequence of $C^*$-algebras is increasing,how to show that the closure of the union is also a $C^*$-algebra?

Comment: If the sequence is increasing, you show that the union is a $*$-algebra (this is very easy, because you can always work on the bigger $A_n$) and the closure of a $*$-algebra is a C$^*$-algebra. Note that this requires an environment where all the $A_n$ live, otherwise "closure" makes no sense, but you can still take the completion and it will be a C$^*$-algebra since it will be the closure of a normed $*$-algebra that satisfies the C$^*$-identity.

Comment: As you said,it is very easy to check that the union is a $*$-algebra,but how to check that the closure of union satisfy the $C^*$-identity.

Comment: The norm on the $*$-algebra is a $C^*$-norm.

Comment: @math112358: The norm on a C$^*$-algebra is unique. So the norms of the $A_n$ are coherent: there is a single norm, which is a C$^*$-norm.

Comment: I want to prove the closure of union of $A_n$ ,say $A$,is a $C^*$ algebra,I mean how to check that $\|x^*x\|=\|x\|^2,x\in A$?

Comment: You write $x=\lim x_n$, with $x_n\in A_n$. Then $$\|x^*x\|=\lim_n\|x_n^*x_n\|=\lim_n\|x_n\|^2=\|x\|^2.$$